# Как правильно написать "алюминиесодержащий"?

Tags: орфография

Что-то меня замкнуто на этом слове. АлюминиЕсодержащий? Алюминесодержащий? Или как-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё как-то. Алиминийсодержащие и Алюмосодержащие.
Магнийсодержащий, ванадийсодержащий. Чем алюминий хуже? 
Этот вариант обычен в бытовом употреблении и, например, медицине.
Что касается варианта "алюмо", то он вопреки 'Марк Из' не несет какой-то конкретной профессиональной окраски, а является общепринятым технарским жарнонизмом.

Вместе с тем вариант "алюмо" обычен еще и в терминах, соотносимых не с алюминий, но алюминиевый, как некая замена длинному "алюминиево...".

Answer (score 2):

Алюминийсодержащий или алюмосодержащий. Первый вариант больше распространён в металлургии, второй - в химии.

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно - алюминийсодержащий, алюминийсодержащие.

Ну, или еще лучше, на мой взгляд, разбить на два слова - содержащие алюминий